# Unable to run tests from sublime text 3

Tags: ruby, macos, minitest, ubuntu-12.10, sublimetext3

I am trying to running a sample test suite from Sublime Text 3.

This is my example that I created using `bundle gem foo -t minitest`

```
class TestFoo < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_it_has_a_version_number_test
    refute_nil ::Foo::VERSION
  end

  def test_it_does_something_useful_test
    assert true
  end
end
```

I have installed the RubyTest package, and the binding to run the test suite is `Ctrl + Shift + T`

I get the following error:

```
/home/thetuxracer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby:1: Invalid char `\x7F' in expression
/home/thetuxracer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby:1: Invalid char `\x02' in expression
/home/thetuxracer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby:1: Invalid char `\x01' in expression
/home/thetuxracer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby:1: Invalid char `\x01' in expression
/home/thetuxracer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant ELF (NameError)
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

**Observations**:

I have installed ruby 2.0.0p247 using rvm. If I run the tests from the CLI, using

`ruby -Itest foo_test.rb` the tests run fine.

I also ensured that the key `check_for_rvm` in RubyTest.sublime-settings is set to `true`

What seems to be the problem here? Please let me know if there is anymore information that you may need to help me out.

EDIT: I tried this on a Mac Os X 10.8.4 with ST3 and ruby 2.0.0p247. In the Rakefile, I have also added this line `t.test_files = FileList['test/test_*.rb']` in the RakeTask.

I looked at this [bug](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests/issues/131) and started ST from the shortcut. But the tests still didnt run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything, from changing configurations in existing projects where the minitest runs, to re-installing the ST3 package to reinstalling ruby itself as a last resort. The problem, it turns out was *way* smaller.

When I execute this command `bundle foo -t minitest` the following files are created:

```
bundle gem foo -t minitest
      create  foo/Gemfile
      create  foo/Rakefile
      create  foo/LICENSE.txt
      create  foo/README.md
      create  foo/.gitignore
      create  foo/foo.gemspec
      create  foo/lib/foo.rb
      create  foo/lib/foo/version.rb
      create  foo/test/minitest_helper.rb
      create  **foo/test/test_foo.rb**
      create  foo/.travis.yml
```

Notice the name of the file containing test cases. I renamed it to `foo_test` and it just worked.

I now need to figure out, why minitest needs the filename in that particular format and if possible, change/edit it.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [this issue](https://github.com/bradphelan/wkhtmltopdf-heroku/issues/2), it's probably related to your bundler generated binstubs.

Looking at the [RVM docs](http://rvm.io/integration/bundler), you might want to try running:

```
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

or:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

If you still have issues after that, I'd try totally removing the binstubs.
Instructions for doing that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662586/how-to-prevent-bundler-from-generating-binstubs).

Comment: I had a similar issue (first four lines with chars were identical), and it was solved by running `bundle install --no-binstubs`.